# Change mousecursor above external <iframe>

Tags: css, iframe, cursor

I have a

```html
<div style="cursor: move;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="h**p://www.some-external-js"></script>
</div>
```

the external JS loads some iframe with content:
`<iframe src="somesource"></iframe>`

I would love to change the mousecursor above the iframe, which is in my div box.
Unfortunately this is not possible with CSS alone, because the iframes overwrites the cursor settings? Any idea?

Comment: What is the point of changing the mouse cursor? **is continuosly surprised at the weird crazy unorthodox requests (hackish) people usually have**

Comment: i have several div boxes with weather, news etc. (google widgets) and would like to make them completely dragable - which works expect the mouse cursor...

Comment: Could you not set it on the body of the document the iframe loads?

Comment: i would, if i could - but some iframes are not in my hands (like the google widget ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. The Same Origin Policy will block you from modifying any of the iframe document's CSS.

The only thing you could do is overlay the iframe with a transparent div using `position: absolute` and a `z-index`. But then the iframe will become unusable.

Comment: i guess thats it. usally thought there could be another solution, but this one works! :) thank you!