# Changing the mouse cursor on an iframe

Tags: html, css

I want to cancel the mouse cursor from hand to default (where that white arrow appears instead). I have a simple iframe..but I think that there is a link inside the iframe that causes the cursor to change to pointer/hand.. how do I change that behavior?

This doesnt work:

```
iframe{
        cursor:default; 
    }
```

Comment: Is your `iframe` embedded within a `div` that has the cursor set like that?

Comment: There is a already an answer for this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258338/change-mousecursor-above-external-iframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the CSS of iframe src. Add -

```
a{ cursor: default; } //in iframe src CSS
```

if not you can do this with jquery if the iframe is in the same domain -

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("a").css('cursor', 'default');
```

**EDIT:**
If it is facebook like button then check this facebook developer portal, it gives you options to style its components -
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: it is not on the same origin.. it is facebook like button.. i guess there is no other choice?!?